# Problem in Oracle 19c Replication

Tags: oracle, replication, dataguard, archive-log

Replication is working fine on the other servers, however on DB_B there's some problem; It is unable to receive archives.

**Can someone help me out? If I have missed any parameters, please do let me know.**

**EDIT:** Primary is DB_A and DR is DB_B

Configurations on the primary

```
NAME               TYPE   VALUE                                                                                 
------------------ ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
log_archive_dest_5 string service=DB_B ASYNC valid_for=(online_logfile,all_roles) db_unique_name=DB_B 


NAME       TYPE   VALUE                              
---------- ------ ---------------------------------- 
fal_client string DB_A                            
fal_server string DB_C, DB_D, DB_E, DB_B 

NAME               TYPE   VALUE                                               
------------------ ------ --------------------------------------------------- 
log_archive_config string DG_CONFIG=(DB_C,DB_D,DB_E,DB_B,DB_A)
```

TNSPing also successful

On DR

```
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- --------------------------------
fal_client                           string      DB_B
fal_server                           string      DB_C, DB_D, DB_E, DB_A
                                                 
                                                 
                                                 
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- --------------------------------------------------
log_archive_config                   string      dg_config=(DB_C,DB_A,DB_E,DB_D,DB_B)
```

Comment: What specific error message is being generated?

Comment: no error, that's the prblem

Comment: then it's probably a question for Oracle Support, not for this forum. Have you opened a service request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution.**

I used the `v$archive_dest` dynamic view to find out that there was an error in my `alter system set log_archive_dest_5='service=DB_B ASYNC valid_for=(online_logfile,all_roles) db_unique_name=DB_B' scope=both;` command.

I can't use online_logfile for a standby, so I changed the command to:

```
alter system set log_archive_dest_5='service=DB_B ASYNC valid_for=(standby_logfiles,standby_roles) db_unique_name=DB_B' scope=both;
```

The archives are now being sent to `DB_B`